# Why android GridView item cannot click when button inside?

Tags: android, gridview, android-button

`GridView` onItemClick not working.`Button` OnClickListener is work.
When I remove button from it, `GridView` onItemClick work.
Any solution please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text=""/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_to_cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Add"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post code of your click listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in the rootview of your custom GridView item

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ...
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            >
            ...
             <Button
             ...
             /> 
            ...      
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you.